# Fade out and remove an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, fadeout

What I would like to do is fade out and remove an element after a few seconds.

It would be initiated after the play image is clicked.

Have it set so that after the play image is clicked, then a fade out transition would occur a few seconds after, then the element would be removed from the page.

First the play image splits apart.

Then, a few seconds after, a fade out transition would occur on the play image, but not right away, a set time.

And after that it would be removed from the page.

That's what I am trying to do.

code https://jsfiddle.net/caer51sw/

```js
(function iife() {
  "use strict";

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
     
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
    const thewrap = curtain.parentElement.querySelector(".container");
    show(thewrap);
  }

  const cover = document.querySelector(".jacketa");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.curtain.slide {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/1080");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.curtain.slide .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.jacketa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #130e85;
  border: 3px solid #f91f6e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #f9066bf7;
   display: block !important;
}
.j1 .jacketa {
  left: 30px;
}

.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 30px;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 75.4px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .back {
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .front {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear, flicker-1 2s linear 2s infinite both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flicker-1 {

  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  41.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  47.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  48% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.split-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.j1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.j2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.curtain.slide .j1 {
  transform: translateX(-529%);
}

.curtain.slide .j2 {
  transform: translateX(529%);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="curtain">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="tcell">

      <div class="container hide">
        <div class="container-top">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-left"> </div>
      <div class="panel-right"> </div>

      <div class="split-wrap">
        <div class="j1">
          <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
            <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
              <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
              <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
              <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="j2">
          <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
            <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
              <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
              <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
              <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
            </svg>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying the two halves of the play image should gradually fade as the panels move across? Also, do you need the play image to be actually removed from the DOM - is there any problem if it remains in the DOM but not seen?

Comment: I would like it to be removed if that is possible. And yes as the panels move across.

Comment: Have you looked into using CSS animation for the fading after a fixed time? You will need Javascript to actually remove something.

Comment: I have looked into trying to figure out the javascript part.

Comment: How would it be done via the css only?

Comment: Like this? cover.classList.add("fadeout"); or like this? curtain.classList.add("fadeout"); / Would fadeout be placed on the cover or curtain?

Comment: Can you show me how it would be written into the code using a transition?

Comment: How do you add a delay before the transition starts to occur?

Comment: Search for 'how do you add a delay before the transition starts to occur'. (Though I normally add 'MDN' into the query as you then tend to land on a reliable page).

Comment: I found a javascript code that does what I am looking for. https://jsfiddle.net/c7or0vgp/   $('.curtain').click(function() {
      $('.fadeout').delay(500).fadeOut(3000, function() {
          $(this).remove();
      });
  });

/ I am not sure how that would be added to my code in pure javascript. Would you be able to help me with this?

Comment: I need help changing it to vanilla javascript.

Comment: Is that something that is difficult to do? I am not familiar with jquery, and don’t use it in codes.

Comment: Is that something you will be able to help me do? Change the jquery to vanilla javascript? That is the code I am looking for, it just needs to be in vanilla javascript.